# Lubuntu stuck on "Started bpfilter" when boot

Tags: lubuntu

I updated my lubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10 and after installation i restarted the system. When system was up just stuck on that message:

```
Started bpfilter
```

My os is lubuntu and the solve of my question was just for ubuntu, and it has not fix my problem from: [Ubuntu 18.10 stuck on "Started bpfilter" while booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084550/ubuntu-18-10-stuck-on-started-bpfilter-while-booting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i upgraded to ubuntu 19.04 and the same thing happened to me. if you reboot and go to start menu, ubuntu key down to ubuntu recovery and enter it will go through the menus and end up to the start menu boot normaly press enter and it should work. i have a dual boot on my computer

Comment: i installed it again and that was the answer for me but thanks.