# Stuck on boot after installing new nvidia graphics card

Tags: boot, nvidia

After upgrading rtx 2070 super I was able to boot and attempt to install the drivers. In the middle of installing the is freezed up and would not move. When I restarted I get the following lines:

"/dev/sdc1: clean, 700021/15269888 files, 23005431/61049344 blocks"
"Started bpfilter"

I have let it sit for over 15 minutes with nothing happening. I have gone into recovery mode and purged the Nvidia driver packeges, I have tried to put "nomodeset" in grunt. I have also loaded from a USB and ran boot-repair. The pastebin url for the result is following: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2SYcjxXXD8/

UPDATE

When I try to uncomment the Wayland config I get the following extra errors:

"[11.456037] ccp 000:2f:00.2: sec command 0x4 times out, disabling PSP

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084550/ubuntu-18-10-stuck-on-started-bpfilter-while-booting/1129301

Comment: Let me update my answer, I tried the enable Wayland solution and it gave some other errors

Comment: Did you already disable secure boot in the bios? It can keep you from installing third party drivers.

Comment: Yes secure boot was already disabled in the bios