# ALT-ESC to switch between windows --> window manager is hanging

Tags: gnome-shell, application-switcher

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to switch between two terminals.

Since it is impossible to switch between two terminals with <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> , I use <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>ESC</kbd>.

This works. But once per day the window manager seems to hang.

I can't get a focus to the windows again.

I can only restart the PC and things work again.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: To what does "Is this a bug or feature" refer?

Comment: @DKBose  "Is this a bug or feature"  refers to the window manager hanging and not responding.

Comment: I very much doubt that Alt+Tab not working or that the window manager seeming to hang once per day would be a feature. Do you have access to another machine? If yes, and you don't see the same issues, you'd be able to get some clarity.

Comment: Also what do actually you mean by "Since ALT-TAB does not work..."? Does it do absolutely nothing? Or fails occasionally? Or just doesn't do what you want it to do? Solving that issue first sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @pomsky  "Since ALT-TAB does not work..." was changed to "Since it is impossible to switch between two terminals with ALT-TAB , I use ALT-ESC."

Comment: @guettli "*impossible*" is a bit of an overstatement, I would have chosen something like "*not possible by default*": https://askubuntu.com/q/747541/480481

Answer (score 4):

This is a Gnome oddity that I dislike as well. I think it's considered a "feature" which I'll call application stacking. Hitting Alt-TAB brings up the terminal showing both terminals and you have to click the one you want to get to it. Quite annoying (at least for me). I got around this in 18.04 by installing [Unity](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=unity&searchon=names) which defaults to the behaviour you and I seem to expect/desire.

This process is very easy.

1. [Enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)
2. Install Unity
   `sudo apt install unity`
3. Select Unity from the Gear Icon prior to login. (You can always go back to gnome via the same icon if desired)

Note that installing unity will install a rather large number of packages (~59)required to support it. However if having the system work as you desire is worth the space (~30MB) it takes for you it's well worth it.

Another alternative possibility is the use of extensions shuch as [Coverflow](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) or [AlternateTab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/) However I have not tested those as of this writing.

You could also customize the keybindings as discussed [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/394376/how-to-prevent-gnome-shells-alttab-from-grouping-windows-from-similar-apps)

As far as the display manager hanging you might find [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032639/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-in-boot-after-starting-gnome-display-manager-on-intel-graphic) useful.

Comment: Has Unity a future? AFAIK ubuntu switched to gnome.

Comment: Switching to Unity just for this is kinda overkill imo, [AlternativeTab](https://askubuntu.com/a/747542/480481) extension can easily provide the feature. In fact it's possible even without using any extensions: https://askubuntu.com/a/1107542/480481

Comment: @guettli If I could tell the future I'd be rich beyond my wildest dreams. Unity is still available though.

Comment: @pomsky Thank you for sharing! I wasn't aware of AlternateTab.