# Alt ^ freezes keyboard

Tags: 18.04, gnome, freeze

If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd> Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome) freezes.

I can still move the mouse and I can shutdown the PC.

But keyboard input is frozen.

I press this combination sometimes accidentally when I want to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there something I can do to prevent Ubuntu from freezing?

I have german keyboard layout with dead-keys.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is  <ALT><SHIFT> 6  ?   And <ESC>, <CTRL>C , and repeating <ALT><SHIFT> 6 have no effect?  Does this happen regardless of the front application in use?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft what does "<ALT><SHIFT> 6 ? And <ESC>, <CTRL>C , and repeating <ALT><SHIFT> 6" do?

Comment: You have things freezing here as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116659/alt-esc-to-switch-between-windows-window-manager-is-hanging

Comment: And `Alt ^` is pretty far away (on the keyboard) from `Alt+Esc` at least on an standard En-US keyboard. Are they close together on your keyboard?

Comment: @DKBose "^" is directly below ESC on my lenovo keyboard (german layout). I guess the freezing on ALT-ESC comes from accidentally touching ^ instead of ESC.

Comment: On an English keyboard, `Alt ^` requires pressing three keys together: Alt+Shift+6.

Comment: @guettli  I'm using standard (English) nomenclature for "hold down the "ALT" and "SHIFT" and "6" key simultaneously.

Comment: I've asked you [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116659/alt-esc-to-switch-between-windows-window-manager-is-hanging#comment1844342_1116659) and I'll again: does the same problem occur on other machines?

Comment: @DKBose I tried it on a different hardware with same setup (Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome, German keyboard). Unfortunately it is working. It was not reproducible on different hardware. On my hardware it is reproducible.

Comment: So could this then be a hardware issue on this particular machine?

Comment: @DKBose my keyboard is connected via usb. I think the keyboard should be allowed to send broken data is much as it wants to. To desktop must not freeze. The keyboard works for me very nice.

Comment: @DKBose keyboard freeze after alt-^  happens on the internal keyboard and on the sub keyboard. I don't think it is an hardware issue.

Comment: In that case, can you try with a new user on the problematic machine? It could be that some tweak you've made to the current user is causing the issue.

Comment: @DKBose I created a new user on the problematic machine. There it does not freeze. Very strange. I have no  unusual config

Comment: Well, as you've seen, there *is* a difference in behavior. So there *must* be something going on! I hope you figure out what that is: conflicting keyboard shortcuts, reassigned keys, etc. All the best!

Comment: Yep, if a different account works, then there is a corrupted config somewhere, or possibly a strange config that was unintentionally modified.  Fastest and simplest thing to do is back up your "regular" files , copy to a brand new account, and kill the offending account.